# Why is my conditional formatting rule not working?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a google sheet with information in cell A and a check box in cell G (other filled cells in between). I have set a custom rule to change the colour of the row when the checkbox has been ticked. The rule works for all 2000 rows eg when checkbox is ticked in any row it works, however only cell A changes colour, not the whole row.

My formula is:  [image]

Why is this only changing column A?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your rule to be an absolute result. Here's a mockup I made that does what I think you want.

[image]